# Linked List priority queue doesn't enqueue before lowest priority

Tags: c

Trying to implement a priority queue such that it displays the following:

```
OUTPUT:
Before Insertion: 4, 5
After Insertion: 2, 4, 5, 7
```

I am using the following function to enqueue in the linked list:

```
void Enqueue(Node* head, int d){
    Node* start = (head);
    Node* temp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->data = d;
    if(head->data > d){
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
    }
    else{
        while (start->next != NULL && start->next->data < d) {
            start = start->next;
        }
    }
    temp->next = start->next;
    start->next = temp;

}
```

However, when using this to get the output, i get the following instead:

```
OUTPUT:
Before Insertion: 4, 5
After Insertion: 4, 2, 5, 7
```

The function seems to work for numbers in between, or numbers at the end.
But it seems to always insert after the first number if the number inserted is lower.

Comment: You pass the function parameter `head` as value. The function sees a copy of the value that the caller passes. If you want to change the value outside the function you have to pass a pointer to the `Node*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function never actually changes the head pointer of your priority queue. It can't, because you pass `head` by value. Instead you should be passing a pointer to it:

```
void Enqueue(Node** head, int d){
    Node* temp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->data = d;

    if ((*head)->data > d) {
        temp->next = *head;
        *head = temp;
        return;
    }

    Node* start = *head;

    while (start->next && start->next->data < d) {
        start = start->next;
    }

    temp->next = start->next;
    start->next = temp;
}
```

I have taken the liberty to clean up your code a bit too.